# How to login to RQM using REST API?

Tags: rest, http-headers, ibm-jazz

I'm trying to communicate with IBM Rational Quality Manager server using its [REST API](https://sleroyblog.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/querying-rqm-40-through-oslc-and-rest-api/). I'm using RESTClient browser plugin, and while the browser is logged in, everything works as expected. For the record, my requests look like

```
https://server/qm/service/com.ibm.rqm.integration.service.IIntegrationService/resources/project/testscript/urn:com.ibm.rqm:testscript:42
```

However, if I wait long enough for RQM to logout, REST API says I need to login back to proceed (see below). I'm pretty sure this is possible to do via the API itself, because RQM ships with [RQMUrlUtility](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21679142) which accepts username and password and runs basically the same REST requests I'm using:

```
java -jar RQMUrlUtility.jar -command GET -user JazzUserID -password JazzPassword -filepath pathtoFile -url REST_URL
```

So far, I have found [this topic](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/105596/rqm-rest-api-for-creating-test-case?redirect=%2Fforum%2Fquestions%2F105596%2Frqm-rest-api-for-creating-test-case) explaining how to login using HTTP basic authentication. Following this advice, I have added `Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=` (not my real password) to the request, but RQM still fails to login. I have also tried setting `User-Agent` to a bogus value, as well as sending the value from `JSESSIONID` in `X-Jazz-CSRF-Prevent` header as described [here](https://sleroyblog.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/querying-rqm-40-through-oslc-and-rest-api/#PutPostSection), but regardless of all these headers being present or not, I get the same response:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2016 15:48:02 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=100
Set-Cookie: JazzFormAuth=Form; Path=/qm; Secure
x-com-ibm-team-scenario=ac55f959-c738-4ef0-854d-6e37648edcba%3Bname%3DInitial+Page+Load%3Bextras%3D%2Fqm%2Fauth%2Fauthrequired%2C1453823282026; Path=/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0
X-com-ibm-team-repository-web-auth-msg: authrequired
```

Can anyone with experience with RQM API tell me what's wrong? Or perhaps I'm missing something basic, common to most RESP APIs out there?

Comment: Question viewed 23 times in two weeks... is SO the right place to ask about Web APIs? Did I miss a more appropriate site?

Comment: There's probably just not a lot of people with IBM services experience, compared to other services.

Comment: Seems odd that you get a 200 response and not 401 or 403, not very RESTful.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be your header name?

```
Authorisation: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

Should probably be:

```
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

Notice the "z".

Comment: Good catch! Unfortunately, this typo is only in my question, not in my code. I have actually tried `Authorisation: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ= `, but RQM response remains the same regardless of the headers I specify.

Comment: Is this of any help? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/tutorials/testrqmrestapiwithrptextensionforsoaquality/

Comment: This looks helpful, but my RQM instance returns a 404 error on any `/jazz` resource. We'll have a couple of IBM guys available next week, I'll ask them (maybe RQM isn't configured right).